# Is there such a thing a 'domain' variables in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to set a variable globally in node.js on a per domain-like basis? I say domain-like because at first I though of creating a domain and attaching a value to it so any piece of code that runs inside the domain will have access to it. The code would have looked similar to this:

```
var myDomain = domain.create()
myDomain.someVariable = 1;
myDomain.run(function () {
    console.log(domain.getCurrentDomain().someVariable);
});
```

Unfortunately, that's not how domains work and can be used. Is there something similar to this that can be done however?

Having nested scopes is not a solution because there's multiple files involed.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5242 https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5243

Comment: Could you use a global object with keys for each "domain" you want to use?